# Springboot,maven dependencies error

Tags: maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a sample spring boot app to deploy in my system which is throwing me following error.I tried cleaning up the maven files from cache still struck with the issue. Can anyone help me with this. Following is the error I Get

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.broad.gateway:com-
 gateway:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact 
 org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE from/to 
 central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out and 
 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

Comment: It looks like you have network errors ...My assumption you need to use a firewall/proxy configuration which you seemed to be not using...

Comment: So should I do that manually? Could you guide me through this process please since I am new to this process

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: I included settings.xml in my file too still it throws the same error. Should I use that code in the link above into my code anywhere? or any changes?

Comment: The issue was with maven dependencies. I fixed that my installing maven locally. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are getting connection timeout error. This generally happens when you are behind a corporate firewall and your company restricts connection to maven central or any other repos. Try defining your company specific nexus repository under pom.xml in `repositories` section.